# Compare lines in two .txt files, print out new line for not contained words

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following piece of code that, for every line in textfile1, searches textfile2 and if  the line is contained in textfile2 prints out the corresponding line of textfile2. I want to however, print out new line for every line not contained in textfile2. Here is the code:

```
def readline():
with open("textfile1.txt") as file, open("textfile2.txt") as file2:
    string = set(map(str.rstrip,file))
    for line in file2:
        spl = line.split(None, 1)[0]
        if spl in string:
            print(line.rstrip())    
        else:              ##if spl not in string print new line
            print("\n")
```

It doesn't work as I expect (doesn't print out any new lines), what may be the problem or any alternative solutions?

Sample Textfile1:

```
'
a
aa
ab
abandon
abandonaudiofocus
abandonsession
abort
abortablehttprequest
abortanimation
abortcaptures
abortconnection
abortpolicy
abortrequest
abs
```

Sample Textfile2:

```
'                |            22624
a                |               91
aa               |                7
ab               |                6
abort            |                8
abortanimation   |                5
abs              |              131
abslistview      |              115
absolutelayout   |               50
absolutesizespan |                6
abstracthttpentity |                2
abstractlist     |                1
abstractmap      |                4
abstractselector |                1
abstractset      |                2
```

Textfile1 includes many more words and it contains all the words in textfile2.

Comment: According to your question *every line in textfile1, searches textfile2 and if the line is contained in textfile2 prints out the corresponding line of textfile2* , you have the files backward?

Comment: Since you have a function do you call you function? sound there is no proble with your code!

Comment: Could you please clarify if your equestion line - *every line in textfile1, searches textfile2 and if the line is contained in textfile2 prints out the corresponding line of textfile2* is the correct one? Or what your code is trying to do - which is for every line in file2 check if it exists in file1 ?

Comment: I want to have output of textfile2 according to the lines of textfile1  and add  new line for lines that don't have a match in textfile2

Comment: Textfile1 includes many more words and it contains all the words in textfile2

Comment: The code you have posted works, if finds words from the first textfile that are in the second.

Comment: please post expected output?

Comment: The expected output was as Anand S Kumar posted in his results, thanks anyway for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question -

> for every line in textfile1, searches textfile2 and if the line is contained in textfile2 prints out the corresponding line of textfile2

And comment -

> Textfile1 includes many more words and it contains all the words in textfile2

The logic you have right now if actually opposite, it checks for each line in `file2`  - `textfile2.txt` - whether that line's first part exists in the `file` - `textfile1.txt` - which would always be true, according to your comment.

You need to get all elements (first part of each line) of file2 in the set and then check each line of `file`. Example -

```
def get_first(line):
    return line.split(None, 1)[0]

def readline():
    with open("textfile1.txt",'r') as file, open("textfile2.txt",'r') as file2:
        string = set(map(get_first,file2))
        file2.seek(0)
        file2_dict = {}
        for line in file2:
            file2_dict[line.split(None, 1)[0]] = line
        for line in file:
            if line.strip() in string:
                print(file2_dict[line.rstrip()])    
            else:              ##if spl not in string print new line
                print()
```

Also, you do not need `"\n"` inside your `print()` in else part, print also puts a newline by itself , you can just do - `print()` to print a newline.

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> def get_first(line):
...     return line.split(None, 1)[0]
...
>>> def readline():
...     with open("a.txt",'r') as file, open("b.txt",'r') as file2:
...         string = set(map(get_first,file2))
...         for line in file:
...             if line.strip() in string:
...                 print(line.rstrip())
...             else:              ##if spl not in string print new line
...                 print()
...
>>> readline()
a
aa
ab



abort

abortanimation




abs
```

In the above example, `a.txt` contains data from your example `textfile1.txt` and `b.txt` contains data from example of `textfile2.txt` .

Comment: It does reverse the elements, and it calls split on the file - `textfile2.txt` .

Comment: `a                |               91` to get `a` .

Comment: or sorry, that was a part remaining from op's code, fixed it, thank you.

Comment: I would like to thank you both for the answers. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Anand, I will accept the answer however I noticed that the output contain only the matching word and not the corresponding numbers found in textfile2, I understand your logic but in this case no numbers get printed, if I change textfile1 and textfile2 to reflect my logic, I get an error "IndexError: list index out of range", how can I modify the code or text files to get  the corresponding  numbers printed as well?

Comment: Thanks Anand, I checked but didn't get any output, doesn't print out any result.

Comment: You used the new code in the top portion right? Not the Example/Demo part?

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake, yes it works thank you very much Anand.

Answer (score 1):

For every line in `textfile2`, searches first part of it in `textfile1` and if the line is contained in `textfile2` prints out the corresponding line of `textfile2`.

```
def readline():
        file1_list = [line.rstrip() for line in open("textfile1.txt")]
        file2_list = [line.rstrip() for line in open("textfile2.txt")]
        fileo_list = [line if line.split(None, 1)[0] in file1_list else '' for line in file2_list]
        for line in fileo_list:
            print(line)
```

This will print out:

```
'                |            22624
a                |               91
aa               |                7
ab               |                6
abort            |                8
abortanimation   |                5
abs              |              131


.....
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sets](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) make this pretty easy

```
with open("textfile1.txt") as file1:
    textfile_1_set = set(map(str.rstrip, file1))

with open("textfile2.txt") as file2:
    textfile_2_set = set([l.split()[0] for l in file2])

# remove all the lines that are in textfile2 from the 
# set of lines from textfile1
in_1_but_not_2 = textfile_1_set - textfile_2_set

for line in in_1_but_not_2:
    print line
```

Comment: Note though that the output of this approach isn't necessarily in the same order as they entries appear in the file. Not sure whether that's a requirement or not. Keeping the `| <number>` parts from `textfile2.txt` would also require some extra code.